# Global variables in laravel 5.2 controllers

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want a variable to be shared by other controller methods. This variable can be updated by one controller method and the change should be reflected in other methods? any suggestions ? what is the best practice to do that ? this is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Session;

class test extends Controller
{


public $global;

public function __construct()




 public function a(Request $request){


 $this->global="some value"

 }

 public function b(Request $request){

  echo $this->global;
  //it always return a null 

 }



  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the variable inside your constructor.

```
function _construct() { $this->global = "some value";}
```

So, you don't only want a global variable, you also want that this variable should be changed by other routes as well. The one way to achieve this is using session.

```
function a() {
    session()->put('global_variable', 'set by method a');
    //your other logic
}
```

and from method b...

```
function b() {
    //get the variable set by method a here
    dd(session()->get('global_variable'));
}
```

Comment: yeah, the best option for per controller.

Comment: this didn't work in my case since I tried to set value in method a and it didn't change the value , when i get the value at method b nothing change

Comment: Ok, so you want to change the value from method a and use that 'changed' value in method b? If that is the case then you have to use session.

Comment: Thanks you are great !

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new file in config and use

```
config('your_new_file_name.key')
```

Check this : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-global-variables